# gnuplot and Shell script read many files and create graphs

Tags: shell, gnuplot, scripting-language

ok I am trying to plot graphs for a different set of datafiles (9 in total) So i created this shell script:

```
!/bin/bash
datastorenum=9
PlotOutputLoc=/root/bin/SANscripts/graphs
PlotGname=datastore
Pfext=png
PlotInputName=desktop
PNext=dat
PlotInputLoc=/root/bin/SANscripts/inputdata

write_plotgraph()
{
        i=1
        while [ $datastorenum != $i ]
        do
        gnuplot <<- EOF
        set term png large size 1200,1024
        set output "$PlotOutputLoc/$PlotGname-$i.$Pfext"
        set xdata time
        set timefmt '%H:%M'
        set style data lines
        set ylabel "IOs-Avg-%-kb"
        set ytics 50
        set autoscale
        set xlabel "Hour"
        plot "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:2 title "Total IOs", "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext " using 1:3 title "Read %", "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:4 title "CacheHit %", "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:5 title "Current Kb/sec", "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:6 title "Maximum Kb/sec", "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:7 title "Current IO/sec", "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:8 title "Maximum IO/sec"

        i=$(( $i + 1 ))
        EOF
        done
}

write_plotgraph
```

It doesnt work exaclty i get bunch of this:

```
     line 0: warning: Skipping unreadable file "/root/bin/SANscripts/inputdata/desktop-1.dat "
     line 0: warning: Skipping unreadable file "/root/bin/SANscripts/inputdata/desktop-1.dat "
     line 0: warning: Skipping unreadable file "/root/bin/SANscripts/inputdata/desktop-1.dat "
```

Thanks for the help

Ok so now what about if I want to pass another function? I like this function to only graph the totalio?

```
write_plotTios()
{
        i=1
        while [ $datastorenum != $i ]
        do
        gnuplot <<- EOF
        set term png large size 1200,1024
        set output "$PlotOutputLoc/$PlotGname-$i-$TIOS.$Pfext"
        set xdata time
        set timefmt '%H:%M'
        set style data lines
        set ylabel "IOs-Avg-%-kb"
        set ytics 50
        set autoscale
        set xlabel "Hour"
        plot "$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext" using 1:2 title "Total IOs"

        EOF
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))
        done
}

write_plotTios
```

this doesn't work i get an error that says:

```
 /plot_datastore1t.sh: line 54: warning: here-document at line 37 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./plot_datastore1t.sh: line 55: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Are they all `desktop-1.dat`? -- Also, what gnuplot version?

Comment: nevermind i had to delete the whitespace from EOF it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the arguments passed to the "plot" command has a trailing space following it.  It's possible that this is being interpreted as part of the filename.  Remove the trailing space and see if the behavior improves.

You use the construct "`$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext`" many times.  You may find it less error-prone (and more readable) to store this as a variable instead of copy/pasting the same thing over and over.

Also, your code that increments the `i` variable is inside the script that gets passed to gnuplot.  The bash variable `i` in never being updated, so you'll loop continuously.  Try swapping your `EOF` and `i=$(( $i + 1 ))` lines.

Comment: how would i define a variable for $PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext?

Comment: @user1814718- The same way that you would define any other shell variable.  Try adding `infile="$PlotInputLoc/$PlotInputName-$i.$PNext"` inside of your while loop but outside of your here-doc.